# Makefiles output directory

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I am a bit a beginner in using makefiles and I am trying to write a makefile for gcc that accepts the inputs from two different directories (in my case they are called kernel and drivers) and output the object files in a different directory (called tmp) using wildcards.

I have written this code to get the names of input files and output files

```
C_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(KERNEL_DIR)/*.c $(DRIVERS_DIR)/*.c)

#Creating a list for object files names
C_OBJ = $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)
```

and I am using the following rule

```
%.o: %.c $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

but i can't get to output the object files in the desired directory.files

Answer (score 2):

Something like this example should do it for you.  I split things up a bit for readability, but I'm sure you'll get the idea:

```
KERNEL_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(KERNEL_DIR)/*.c)
DRIVER_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(DRIVER_DIR)/*.c)

OBJECTS =  $(patsubst $(KERNEL_DIR)/%.c,tmp/%.o,$(KERNEL_SOURCES))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(DRIVER_DIR)/%.c,tmp/%.o,$(DRIVER_SOURCES))
```

Watch out for source files with the same name in both `KERNEL_DIR` and `DRIVER_DIR`!

Comment: and how should I modify the rule ?
I use the following one
'%.o: %.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@'

Comment: @PatrickJane, that's a harder one.  Since you only want a single output directory, it's going to be tough.  I'd recommend you don't do that, but instead mirror the input directory structure in `tmp` - then you will have a 1:1 mapping of each `.o` file to a `.c` file and make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a separate rule for each subdirectory, like this:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(KERNEL_DIR)/*.c $(DRIVER_DIR)/*.c)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(SOURCES)))

all: $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o : $(KERNEL_DIR)/%.c
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o : $(DRIVER_DIR)/%.c
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Obviously you'll have big problems if you have a `foo.c` file in both source directories...